# Extracting Patterns affects my numeric variables in Data frame

Tags: r

I have a data set which includes some characters on it, so I tried this

```
Data.df[] <- lapply(Data.df, sub, pattern='T', replacement='')
Data.df[]<- lapply(Data.df, sub, pattern='D', replacement='')
```

Because my dataset is huge with date, time and more variables numeric, when I tried this to fix the patterns it makes my columns non numeric. Can you help me? Why this code affects my other column variables?

Comment: Just run it on the character columns only

Comment: You can pick only character column by running this , `char_col <- names(df)[vapply(df, is.character, logical(1))]`, whatever columns its throwing, run your function on those only, something like this : `df[,char_col] <- lapply(df[,char_col], your_function_here)`

Answer (score 0):

You could check first:

```
Data.df[] <- lapply(
    Data.df, 
    function(x) if(is.character(x)) sub(x, pattern='T', replacement='') else x,
)
```